# Sum of array elements counted dynamic by JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have loop like this:

```
while((numbers[0]+numbers[1]+numbers[2]+numbers[3]+numbers[4]+numbers[5]+numbers[6]
        +numbers[7]+numbers[8]+numbers[9]+numbers[10]+numbers[11]+numbers[12]+numbers[13]
        +numbers[14]+numbers[15]+numbers[16]+numbers[17]+numbers[18]+numbers[19]+numbers[20]
        +numbers[21]+numbers[22]+numbers[23]+numbers[24]+numbers[25]+numbers[26]+numbers[27]
        +numbers[28]+numbers[29]+numbers[30]+numbers[31]) != 0 )
    {
        x=Math.floor((Math.random() * 32) + 0);

        if (numbers[x]!=0) {
            $('.board').append('<div class="tile" data-icon="icon'+(numbers[x])+'" data-end="no"></div>');
            numbers[x]=0;
        } 
    }
```

I wanna make my while condition more *sexy*. I need a sum of 'numbers' elements.
In loop, values of array elements are changing, so I guess I can't count it by *for* loop, dynamic counting is necessary. Is some function for that?
I'll be grateful for any help with solution my problem.

Comment: Why not use `Array.prototype.reduce` instead? Or a `forEach`?

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** with ES6 arrow function in latest browsers

```
while(numbers.reduce((a,b) => a+b ) != 0 )
```

or with function

```
while(numbers.reduce(function(a,b){ return a+b }) != 0 )
```

---

For older browser check [polyfill option of reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on an array to perform an operation sequentially on each element, and pass on the result of the previous calculation to the next one. This allows you to "sum" the array by adding each value to the previous ones.

```
while(numbers.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev + curr;
}, 0)) {
     // loop body
}
```

In es6 parlance, you can use fat arrow syntax to make this more succient:

```
while(numbers.reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0)) {
    // loop body
}
```

Comment: This gets even smaller in ES2015. `numbers.reduce((a, b) => (a+b))`

Comment: Indeed it does. I'm still a fan of passing in the initial value explicitly however